# Why is one form button executing actions for all form buttons?

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I am using Flask to make a simple webpage with 3 form buttons. Two of these buttons, Draw and Reset, have javascript functions that are are supposed to execute when each respective button is pressed; Draw should execute `RegenDivs()` while Reset should execute `ResetPath`.

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" action="{{ url_for('checkButtons') }}">
    <input class="dbtn" type="submit" value="Draw" name="drawbtn"/>
    <input class="hbtn" type="submit" value="Home" name="homebtn"/>
    <input class="rbtn" type="submit" value="Reset" name="resetbtn"/>
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
        document.getElementsByClassName('dbtn').onlick = setTimeout(function regenDivs(){
            console.log("starting regen");
            var storedPath = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("path"));
            var storedRawPath = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("rawPath"));
    
            if(storedRawPath == null){
                console.log("path null");
                storedRawPath = [[0, 160]];
                return 0;
            }else{
                console.log(storedRawPath.toString());
            }

            for(let i = 0; i < storedRawPath.length; i++){
                createDiv(storedRawPath[i][0], storedRawPath[i][1]);
                console.log("Created div at: " + storedRawPath[i][0] + ", " + storedRawPath[i][1]);
            }
             
            path = storedPath;
            rawPath = storedRawPath;

        }, 1000);

        document.getElementsByClassName('rbtn').onclick = setTimeout(function resetPath(){
            clearDivs();
            sessionStorage.removeItem("rawPath");
            sessionStorage.removeItem("path");
            sessionStorage.removeItem("numDivs");
            path = [];
            rawPath = [];
            divArray = [];
            numDivs = 0;

        }, 1000);
```

**Flask/Python**

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def index():    
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route('/buttton', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def checkButtons():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form.get('homebtn') == 'Home':
            print("Starting Homing...")
            #p.home()            
            print("Successfully Homed.")
            return redirect(url_for('checkButtons'))

        if request.form.get('drawbtn') == 'Draw':
            print("starting draw")
            p.draw()
            print("drawing done")
            return redirect(url_for('checkButtons'))

        if request.form.get('resetbtn') == 'Reset':
            print("reset")
            p.reset_path()
            return redirect(url_for('checkButtons'))

    elif request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('index.html')
```

Right now, pressing the "Draw" button not only executes the `regenDivs()` function but also executes the `resetPath()` function which should only execute when I press the "Reset" button. Why does this happen? I'm still pretty new to html/css/javascript so I'm probably doing something very wrong but I can't figure out what.

Comment: Firstly, I don't think you can set an `onclick` of a "NodeList" object representing several elements - which is what `getElementsByClassName` returns. But your real issue is that you are setting it equal to the return value of `setTimeout(yourFunction, someInterval)`, which sets it equal to the timeout ID while initialising the timeout. I think you want to set it to a function which does this: `(yourElement).onclick = () => setTimeout(theFunction, the Interval)` should be closer to what you want.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Seems to be working now, I also created id's for my buttons so I could use getElementById instead of ClassName. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered by @robin-zigmond.
Transcripting his comment to proper answer text area:

You are assigning 'setTimetout' return value to onClick...

> which sets it equal to the timeout ID while initialising the timeout
> [...]  (yourElement).onclick = () => setTimeout(theFunction, the
> Interval) should be closer to what you want